# Determine content length to have a dynamic hr tag

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to determine the length of the content contained inside an h2 element, which changes. So an hr tag can be set to the same length plus some additional width?

so it would look sort of like

I tried some psuedocode to explain what I mean. I would move this to a css rule of course

```
<h2>SOME RANDOM TITLE LENGTH</h2>
<hr style=width_of_H2_plus_5% />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's OK to use `float` or `absolute` positioning then you could try the following:

```
<div style="float: left; width:auto;">
   <h2>SOME RANDOM TITLE LENGTH</h2>
   <hr style="width: 110%; margin-left: -5%;"/>
</div>
```

Unfortunatley, I don't think `width:auto` works with `static` or `relative` positioning.

Comment: I will test this but the width would adjust to the h2 content wouldn't it? I need to extend the hr length beyond the h2 so it matches other stylized headings that are fixed, and look that way

Comment: I've updated the `<hr>` code to do that

Comment: this does achieve what I had hoped, unfortunately they are using sifr which changes the h2 length after the hr length gets calculated. without sifr it does exactly what I wanted. Only needed the width:105% and no margin-left. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible purely with HTML & CSS. You could, however, use some JavaScript to calculate the width of your `<h2>` and then make your `<hr>`'s width `<h2>`'s + 5%. You can use the `window.onload` and `window.onresize` events to update the width of your `<hr>` as the size of the window changes.

Comment: @km kind of what I expected. I think you are right. I was looking at the inherited code and there is sifr which is flash running on that tag as well. So that may give the width after it completes the object. Unless someone tells me otherwise I will count this as the answer. thanks

Comment: I'm glad I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just set the h2 style to underline? H2 is a block element. The hr should be unnecessary.

Comment: I need the underline to go beyond the width of the h2 tag content by 5% to match styling of other elements